# Add inset to box-shadow property in jQuery to update dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have something like this:

```
$('.inset').click(function(){

    if($('.inset').is(':checked')){
        $('.box-shadow').css('boxShadow','inset');
    }else{
        $('.box-shadow').css('boxShadow','');
    }
});
```

That, basically, when a checkbox is checked does somthing and when it's not checked it does another thing.

Well, what I want to do is that when the checkbox is checked, the boxShadow property (which actually is: `box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;` change to `box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px #000;` and when it's not checked, change back to: `box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;`.

That might be simple, but the problem is that the other properties (5px 5px 5px #000) ar not always the same, so, there's a way to do something like this?

```
$('.inset').click(function(){

        if($('.inset').is(':checked')){
            $('.box-shadow').css('boxShadow','+inset');
        }else{
            $('.box-shadow').css('boxShadow','-inset');
        }
    });
```

Comment: -1 because you don't know how to choose the best answer. If the answers seem to be the same, you should choose the one **which was posted first**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.inset').on('change', function(){
    $('.box-shadow').css('boxShadow', function(i,old) {
        return old.indexOf('inset') === -1 ? old + ' inset' : old.replace(/\s+inset/,'')
    });
});
```

which basically uses 'on' and 'css' from jQuery and 'replace' , 'indexOf' from javascript!

Comment: I wonder why this looks the same to David Thomas' code **too much**, it's exactly a copy of David Thomas' code although I'm not sure if you actually copied it. This answer was also posted about **2h 35m** after the David Thomas' code had been posted. The OP should have not chosen this over the David Thomas' answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is:

```
$('.inset').on('change', function(){
    $('.box-shadow').css('boxShadow', function(i,old) {
        return old.indexOf('inset') === -1 ? old + ' inset' : old.replace(/\s+inset/,'')
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u9hGZ/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- JavaScript:

  - [(JavaScript) Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('.inset').click(function(){
    if($('.inset').is(':checked')){
        $('.box-shadow').css('box-shadow','inset 5px 5px 5px #000');
    }else{
        $('.box-shadow').css('box-shadow','5px 5px 5px #000');
    }
});
```

Or make two css classes, one with inset and one without and just switch between them.